# Only Comma separated values in textbox Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I have a text box on my form. I want only a comma separated keyword in that. How to put this type of validation in symfony2. 
I found 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

and
 http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/forms/1_2/en/02-form-validation

but not as I required.

Comment: Give exemple please of what you are expecting, we can't help you there ? And what did you try ?

Comment: i have a text box in which there should be the keywords with the comma separation , i dont know which pattern i need to use for validation

Comment: Does these keywords exist into the DB ? I mean, do you need to checked that all the typed keywords exists within your database ?

Comment: yes will save in DB after validation

Comment: Hi @AnishShah if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

well the validation logic is as simple as

```
if(is_array(explode(",",$input)){
 return true;
}else{
 return false;
}
```

use a custom validator and implement this logic

Answer (score 1):

You should write your [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) for check this requirements, then you can implements a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) so you can manipulate your string as you want. As example, if you are archiving something like a tagging field you can proceed as described.

In the client side you can add a js component that can do this behaviour for you, check [this component](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) in the Tagging support section (you can build a REST service for manage a subset of filed).

Let me know if this is your scenario so i can provide example code about.

Hope this help.